# Exception for one row

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I figure out one issue here. there is one row that causes an exception. if the department entered is 'DENTAL' this app has an exception:

"Index Out of Range Exception is was unhandled by user code"
There is no row at position 0.

```
BHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(); /<
                string sql = @"select distinct ID from OGEN.SCH_C_RESOURCES /<
                        where DESCRIPTION='" + deptName + "' AND FIRST_LEVEL_CAT = 'DEPT' and FACILITY_KEY  IN('" + StaticStuff.FacilityKey + "','BASE') order by 1"; /<
                DataSet ds = dbHelper.DataAdapter(CommandType.Text, sql); /<
                if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"]);
```

Comment: What are you asking - how to handle the exception or how to correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not checking if there are any rows. It is, however, checking that there are tables returned - and I guess the table is empty (contains no rows) which is perfectly valid.

```
if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
```

should probably be

```
if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
```

Oh, and your code is also susceptable to a SQL Injection Attack. You should probably use parameterised queries to guard against that. Here's an article I wrote a while ago about that and how to prevent it: http://colinmackay.co.uk/2005/04/23/sql-injection-attacks-and-some-tips-on-how-to-prevent-them/

Comment: Or maybe don't use a Dataset to return a scalar value

Comment: Indeed. `ExecuteScalar` would work fine for any situation where the result set is the first column, in the first table.